# Data binding on first page load after load ngFor

Tags: angular, data-binding, ngfor

I have a page with a list of options to user choose with a radio button. onclick this binding some data to a summary right a side from a method. I wanna check the last item by default and load the data in the summary as way in the first page load

Anyone has deal with something like that?

Template

```
 <!-- homebasic_cplan start -->
  <section class="homebasic_cplan common_sec">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="mainbox1">
            <div class="title_box1">
              <h2>Choose the plan</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="boxbody1">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6">
                  <h3 class="choose_head">Choose the plan that best suits you</h3>
                  <form class="form_hlp">
                      <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of items; let isLast = last">
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <div class="borer_bottom">
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-5 padleft0">
                                  <label class="contain">{{item.months}} {{item.title}}
                                    <input (click)="selectplan(baselineRate-baselineRate*item.discount/100,item.months)" type="radio" name="radio" [checked]="isLast">
                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="col-7 padright0">
                                    <p class="rs_plan" >R$ {{baselineRate-baselineRate*item.discount/100}}/mo</p>
                                    <p class="rs_plan1">R$ {{baselineRate}}/mo</p>
                                    <p class="rs_plan2">Save {{item.discount}}% with discount</p>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 offset-lg-1">
                    <div class="summary_box clearfix">
                      <h3>SUMMARY</h3>
                      <p class="home_protxt">{{productname}}<span class="rs_txt1">${{totalprice | number : '1.2-2'}}</span> </p>
                      <p class="mnth_txt">For {{duration}} months</p>
                      <div class="line"></div>
                      <p class="dis_txt">${{totalprice | number : '1.2-2'}}</p>
                      <p class="home_protxt">TOTAL<span class="rs_txt">{{duration}}x of <sup>${{price}}</sup>,<sub>00</sub> </span> </p>


                      <a class="btn btn_apply" (click)="homestartnow()">START NOW</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- homebasic_plan end -->
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonService } from '../../services/common.service';
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';
import { AuthenticationService } from './../../services/authentication.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-homebasic-cplan',
  templateUrl: './homebasic-cplan.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homebasic-cplan.component.css'],
  providers: [CommonService]
})
export class HomebasicCplanComponent implements OnInit  {
  /*Declare varialbles */
  items: any;
  baselineRate: any;
  productname: any;
  price: any;
  totalprice: any;
  duration: any;
  id: any;

  private _planUrl = 'subscription/getSubscriptionById';

  constructor(
    public _commonService: CommonService,
    public router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
    localStorage.removeItem('totalprice');
    localStorage.removeItem('price');
    localStorage.removeItem('duration');
    localStorage.removeItem('planName');

    /*getting the route id from here */
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      localStorage.setItem('subid', params['id']);
      this.getData(params['id']);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.price = '0.00';
    this.totalprice = '0.00';
    this.duration = '0';
  }

  /*Get the subscription by id */
  getData(id) {
    const value = {
      subscriptionId: id
    };

    this._commonService.callingpostapi(this._planUrl, value).subscribe(
      response => this.handleResponse(response),
      error => this.handleResponse(error)
    );
  }

  handleResponse(response) {
    this.items = response.result.subscriptionData[0].discounts;
    this.baselineRate = response.result.subscriptionData[0].feesCharge.baselineRate;
    this.productname = response.result.subscriptionData[0].product_name;
  }

  /*select the plan and set the value in local storage */
  selectplan(price, duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
    this.price = price;
    this.totalprice = duration * price;
    localStorage.setItem('totalprice', this.totalprice);
    localStorage.setItem('price', this.price);
    localStorage.setItem('duration', this.duration);
    localStorage.setItem('planName', this.productname);
    console.log( this.totalprice);
  }

  /*login check for routing */
  homestartnow() {
    if (
      this.authenticationService.getAccessToken() &&
      this.authenticationService.getUser()
    ) {
      this.router.navigate(['/homebasicstart']);
    } else {
      sessionStorage.setItem(
        environment.storageConstants.LANDING_PAGE_AFTER_LOGIN,
        JSON.stringify('/homebasicstart')
      );
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
  }
}
```